# Why can't I get a Symbol to move up and down towards the mouse in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

I want the `Symbol`(named player) to move on the `y` axis towards my mouse. The code I wrote only moves it up and i can't figure out why it wont follow my mouse and move down.

This is the section of code:

```
if (mouseY < player.y){
    player.y -= playerYSpeed;
}
else if(mouseY > player.y)
{
    player.Y += playerYSpeed;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
player.Y += playerYSpeed;
```

you've capitalize the y property, it needs to be lower case.

```
player.y += playerYSpeed;
```

Comment: Hi @MikeTrapp. Mark the Aesphere answer as the right answer.